# executing a while loop between defined time

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a while loop only under a defined time like this, but the while loop continues its execution even when we are above the defined limit :

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

minute = now.minute

while minute < 46 :
    print "test"
    time.sleep(5)
    minute = now.minute
```

How can stop the loop once we cross the limit ?

Thanks

Comment: `now` is defined outside `while` and hence, will be a constant value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not updating the value of `minute` inside while loop properly. You should recalculate the value of `now` in loop and then assign the new `now.minute` to `minute`.

```
while minute < 46 :
    print "test"
    time.sleep(5)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    minute = now.minute
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to determine the time anew in your loop. The `minute` variable is *static*, it does not update to reflect changing time.

If you want to loop for a certain *amount* of time, start with `time.time()` instead and then calculate elapsed time:

```
import time

start = time.time()

while time.time() - start < 300:
    print 'test'
    time.sleep(5)
```

will print 'test' every 5 seconds for 5 minutes (300 seconds).

You can do the same with `datetime` objects of course, but the `time.time()` call is a little simpler to work with.

To loop *until* a certain time `datetime` can be used like:

```
import datetime

while datetime.datetime.now().minute < 46:
    print 'test'
    time.sleep(5)
```

Again, note that the loop needs to call a method *each time* to determine what the current time is.

Answer (score 1):

The loop's proposition should be `datetime.datetime.now().minute - minute < 46` and the body of the loop shouldn't be updating `minute`.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the current time in `now` variable. Instead you should get the current time inside the loop everytime:

```
import datetime
import time

minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute

while minute < 46 :
    print "test"
    time.sleep(5)
    minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute
```